# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) returns String.Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, environment

i have an asp.net mvc3 application. Now i want to save userdata in

> C:\Users{AppPoolUserAccount}\AppData\Roaming\MyProgramm...

On first call of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` i only get "" (String.Empty). 
On second call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returns correct path...

Note:
The routine is in a Login-Context. I want to save username and sessionID in a xml-file
to prevent that two users are logged in simultaneously via one user-account.

Why?

Comment: Maybe related: [IIS 7.5 application pool uses wrong %APPDATA% for custom user as identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490107/iis-7-5-application-pool-uses-wrong-appdata-for-custom-user-as-identity)

Answer (score 7):

`Environment.GetFolderPath` returns empty strings for most of the SpecialFolder enum values because the user profile for the user you are using to run the app pool is not loaded.

You need to configure the app pool to load the user profile either by going into IIS Manager > Application Pools > YourAppPool > Advanced Settings > Load User Profile, and setting the value to "true" or by opening up a command prompt and running

```
appcmd set apppool "MyAppPool" -processModel.loadUserProfile:true
```

(usually you'll run this in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv).

Here are a couple of links with more data:

- [loadUserProfile and IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/18/loadUserProfile-and-IIS7-_2D00_-understanding-temporary-directory-failures.aspx) (This one says that loading the profile is the default, which it
  isn't, but it is correct otherwise.  Maybe they changed the default
  between 7 and 7.5?)
- [Process Model Settings for an Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/processModel)

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Profile loading is default in 8.0, but unfortunately it isn't helping matters.

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.GetFolderPath`returns an empty string **by design** *if the folder does not exist*.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx%20MSDN):

> Environment.GetFolderPath Method (Environment.SpecialFolder)

Return Value Type: System.String

> The path to the specified system special folder, if that folder
> physically exists on your computer; otherwise, an empty string ("").
>
> A folder will not physically exist if the operating system did not
> create it, the existing folder was deleted, or the folder is a virtual
> directory, such as My Computer, which does not correspond to a
> physical path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data (for example currently logged users) try use this code:

In global.asax, when application starts:

```
 var users = new List<Guid>();
 Application["loggedUsers"] = users;
```

Then if user is logging on, type this:

```
var users = (List<Guid>)Application["loggedUsers"];
users.Add(currentlyLoggingOnUserId);
Application["loggedUsers"] = users;
```

Comment: how long this information is been saved? also after an server/site-restart?

Comment: No, server restart clean application data