# IIS 7.5 system variables for app pool

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, environment-variables

I had a problem with logging in my ASP.NET MVC project and with IIS in generally.

My local IIS has default configuration and I try to get `appData` folder path for start logging into this (for example I wanna put my log files into `%Appdata%/MyProject/logfile.log`). So I run my site and get my log folder into `C:\MyProject\Logfile.log`. As I understand my application pull has a null value of environment value `%AppData%`. Also i find this questions

[IIS 7.5 application pool uses wrong %APPDATA% for custom user as identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490107/iis-7-5-application-pool-uses-wrong-appdata-for-custom-user-as-identity)

and

[NetworkService under IIS has empty AppData path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056626/networkservice-under-iis-has-empty-appdata-path).

Now i wanna know how to solve problem (get environment value `%AppData%` for personal app pools) and also can fix this issue from GUI (IIS or something else - not all time i has access to iis config directory).

Comment: Are you using a specific logging framework?  Log4Net is highly recommended.

Comment: Hi, yeap i know about Log4Net but i using in my projects NLog logging system. I can change log system but i wanna still know about ISS app pools and system variables.