# IIS ApplicationPool user has incorrect USERPROFILE / TEMP value

Tags: iis, applicationpoolidentity

I've run into an issue that was originally exposed by `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator` throwing an `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to c:\Users\[wrong-user]\AppData\Local\Temp` receiving an "access denied" error attempting to write into a *different* IIS AppPool user's temp directory.

I have another application which actually runs as the `[wrong-user]` AppPool, and that application *does* work. However, this makes sense, since it has write access to it's own user directory.

I've narrowed the error down to the fact that `%USERPROFILE%` is returning the path of a different IIS APPPOOL user, even though `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` returns the *correct* path.

If I enumerate `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(User)`, I get:

- Path - C:\Users\[wrong-user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
- TEMP - C:\Users\[wrong-user]\AppData\Local\Temp
- TMP - C:\Users\[wrong-user]\AppData\Local\Temp

Additionally, manually accessing the user's environment variables via `HKEY_USERS/[SID]/Environment` confirms that it is simply down to `%USERPROFILE%` being incorrect:

- Path - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
- TEMP - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
- TMP - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being that `setProfileEnvironment`, which isolates the environment variables for each application pool's worker processes, was set to `false` on `system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults` despite it [having a default value of `true` according to the documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel#005). Since none of the application pools were overriding it, they all received the same value and thus shared common environment variables.

I have no idea how it got set to `false`, nor how the shared `USERPROFILE` environment variable got set to one application pool but never another, but setting the default value back to `true` resolved the issue.

It was this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9490107/3603) which helped me find the cause, despite the problem being different.